# Counting in TWIG

Tags: php, twig, silex

I'm using SILEX with twig and I'm trying to achieve an count for an array from db with a specific value
Here is the piece of code to be more specific:

```
 <p>There are in total {{ items|length }}</p> // returns the GOOD amount of total rows in db
 <p>There are  {{ items.stare=='activ'|length }} requests not answered.</p> // returns nothing
```

How can I achieve what I want?

items is an array with information from a `SELECT *`

EDIT

I'm sorry , the second returns nothing only when using an for(items as item)
When I use items.stare I get a twig error:

```
Key "stare" for array with keys "0, 1, 2, 3, 4" does not exist in "index.twig" at line 78
```

Comment: `items.stare=='activ'` returns a `boolean`, which doesn't really have a length in this context - you need to filter the array (probably in PHP).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably count them in SQL, with a `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ... WHERE stare == 'active'` or something, and pass that into your twig template.

Or, you could filter it in PHP and pass the filtered array to your template:

```
$activ_items = array_filter($items, function($item) {
    return $item['stare'] == 'active';
});

<p>There are in total {{ items|length }}</p> // returns the GOOD amount of total rows in db
<p>There are  {{ activ_items|length }} requests not answered.</p> // returns nothing
```

If you really want to do it all in twig, which I don't recommend, you could do:

```
<p>There are in total {{ items|length }}</p> // returns the GOOD amount of total rows in db
{% set count = 0 %}
{% for item in items %}
    {% if item.stare == "activ" %}
        {% set count = count + 1 %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
<p>There are  {{ count }} requests not answered.</p> // returns nothing
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I used the filtering example but first I tried the SELECT COUNT(*). How can I return the value of that variable in twig after I've rendered it in the template? If i'd use lets say $select_count and in twig {{ select_count }} , It would return Array and using |length would return 1 (it makes sense) . So how can I return the value of it?

Comment: I don't understand your question, what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I edited the comment . I simply want to return the value inside the array (that is passed in twig as an variable) in the twig template

Comment: Oh, I see, well ideally you would not pass it as an array at all, but I don't know how it is getting to twig in your program, so I guess you would just do `{{ select_count.0 }}` to get the first item from the array